# jquery post, how to know php form did what it was asked to do

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a simple form to delete users from the DB -

```
<form role="form" class="delete_user" method="post" action="/user_delete.php?id='+ID+'"><button type="submit" class="tiny button" name="delete" value="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></form>
```

The PHP -

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . $id);
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "posts_following WHERE user_id = " . $id);
echo '<script>console.log("User deleted? I suppose?")</script>';
} else {
    Leave(FORUM_URL.'users.php');
}
```

The jquery -

```
$('[name="delete"]').click(function(){
                    var Q = confirm('Delete '+NAME+'?');
                    if ( Q === true ) {
                        $.post('/user_delete.php?id='+ID, function(data, status){
                            console.log('Data: '+data);
                            console.log('status: '+status);
                        });
                    }
```

Everything works, however, I'm confused as to how to verify that the user was truly deleted from the DB. Sure, I can use .done() or if (status===200) but I'm not sure if that means the user was actually deleted of just that user_delete.php page was successfully accessed.

Comment: you can do: `if($db->query('your query'))` to check if the query has be ran correctly. If the value is true, then there is no error.

Comment: check affected rows for each and send response according to success of both

Comment: @EmmanuelO Incorrect. `query()` only returns `false` if your SQL fails to execute. If your SQL executes and affects 0 rows, you will not get `false` back

Comment: Why not test for the id existing after delete if you don't trust it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch statement. If any commands inside try block fails, the code will jump to 'catch' block and throw an error message with what happened.

```
try 
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {   // Sets PDO to throw an expcetion if anythig goes wrong on DB operation
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . $id);
        $db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "posts_following WHERE user_id = " . $id);
        echo '<script>console.log("user deleted successfully")</script>';
    } 
    else 
    {
    Leave(FORUM_URL.'users.php');
    }
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
   echo '<script>console.log("user delete fail. Err:' + $e->getMessage() + ' ")</script>';
}
```

Comment: That's nice but... what in that code block throws an exception?

Comment: If any command fails, it automatically throws an exception, you don't need a specific command to throw it. Everything inside 'try' block is kind of monitored and if anything goes wrong an exception is thrown

Comment: Neither `mysqli` nor `PDO` throw exceptions natively. Again, when `$db->query` fails it returns `false` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: To PDO throw exception you must tell him to do that... Use
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: You should add that to your answer then. You can't assume the asker (or anyone who finds this) knows to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `mysqli` for this

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $response = ['success' => true];
    $db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . (int)$id);
    if($db->affected_rows) {
        $db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "posts_following WHERE user_id = " . (int)$id);
    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

What we're doing is checking [affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to see if the query was successful. We're then returning a JSON object so your AJAX request can parse it and see if it was successful. I also cast your user ID so it's less vulnerable to SQL injection. You'll probably want to perform some sort of permissions check to make sure the caller is authorized to delete the user.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . $id);
$db->query("DELETE FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "posts_following WHERE user_id = " . $id);
$response = $db->query("SELECT id FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . $id . " LIMIT 1");
if(mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo '<script>console.log("User deleted successfully")</script>';
} else {
    Leave(FORUM_URL.'users.php');
}
```